# Using Unions vs Multiple structs

Tags: c++

I am quite new in c++, sometimes i am not sure what is better way performance/memory. My problem is that i need struct with exactly two pointers to vec3 (3 floats) and vec3/vec2.

Right now i am trying to decide if use:
- Unions with two constructors, one for vec3 and one for vec2
- Create two structs , one will contain vec2 and one vec3

```cpp
struct vec3
{
    float x,y,z;
};
struct vec2
{
    float x,y;
};
struct Vertex
{
    template <typename F>
    Vertex(vec3 *Vertices,F Frag)
    : m_vertices(Vertices),m_fragment(Frag)
    {}

    union Fragment
    {
        Fragment(vec3 *Colors)
        :colors(Colors)
        {}
        Fragment(vec2 *Texcoords)
        :texcoords(Texcoords)
        {}

        vec3 *colors;
        vec2 *texcoords;

    } m_fragment;


    vec3 * m_vertices;
}
```

This code works well, but i am quite worried about performance, as i intend to use Vertex struct very often, my program might have thousand of instances of Vertex struct.

Comment: "thousand" is nothing to worry about.  The only true way to stop worrying by *measuring*.  It  is quite common that the real bottleneck in a program is located in a place you didn't expect.  If you don't have a decent profiler yet then be sure to go shopping.

Comment: A side note: You can use `Eigen::Vector2f` or `Eigen::Vector3f` if you're going to perform vector calculations with those vectors. Simpler and easier than implementing your own structures and procedures for them

Comment: Thank you, but i already use lib for vectors, I could not send my code right now, this is just replica that should represent my problem.

Answer (score 2):

If every `Vertex` can have *either* `colors` or `texcoords`, but never both, then a `union` (or better yet, a `std::variant<vec3, vec2>`) makes sense.

If a `Vertex` can have *both* `colors` and `texcoords`, then a `union` won't work, since only one member of a `union` can be active at a time.

As for performance, profile, profile, profile.  Build your interface in such a way that the choice of `union` or separate members is invisible to the caller.  Then implement it both ways and test to see which performs better (or if there's a perceptible difference at all).